# How can I kill Bogeyman in Silent Hill: Downpour?

Tags: silent-hill-downpour

At 68% of the game, I heard Charlie's cries for help. Then I ran down to the lake shore, and Bogeyman came out from the lake to attack me. I hit him several times with my axe, but at the end he killed me. I tried for 3 times but he killed me every time. How can I kill him?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to come to some harsh realizations with your past (and then shoot him a few times). No wait, that's Pyramid head...

Comment: Perhaps this would be of help? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcwS_D6Grzg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is how I did it:

I hit him a few times. When he crouched down, I came close to him, and grabbed his sledge hammer (by pressing A on Xbox 360). Then Murphy automatically killed him within the cut scene.